# I have written code for image widget and also given path in pubsec.yaml file then also its showing error

Tags: flutter, dart

this is the error

> Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/login.jpg")
> Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#e28ce(), name: "assets/images/login.jpg",
> scale: 1)

here is my code

```
Image(
     image: AssetImage("assets/images/login.jpg"),
     ),
```

```
    pubsec.yaml
    
      assets:
        - assets/images/
```

Comment: Have you tried to `stop` the app after adding the image in your `assets/images` folder and then `Rerun` the app?

Answer (score 2):

It is bcoz you haven't close your running app

1. close your running app first
2. Re-open app

Answer (score 0):

1. Flutter pub get
2. kill your app
3. And debug or run the app again

as you add the assert in pubspec.yaml you need to restart the application